# What is the Email Admin in the App Engine quotas?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, gae-quotas

I am sending emails with `EmailMessage().send()` from a Python App Engine app. After sending a few test emails to my gmail addres, in the Quota Details page I read this:

```
Recipients Emailed   5%    5%    5 of 100     Okay
Admins Emailed       0%    0%    0 of 5,000   Okay
```

In the Permissions page my email address is the only one listed and it's the owner.

I was expecting emails addressed to the owner of the app to fall in the Admins Emailed quota, not in the Recipients Emailed.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas) it says:

> **Admin Emails**
>   The total number of messages to application admins that
>   have been sent by the application.

What is the Email Admin quota for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `google.appengine.api.mail` package has a function `send_mail_to_admins(sender, subject, body, **kw)` that will send the email to *all* admins of the application, and uses the Admin Emails quota, rather than the general one: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/functions).

Comment: does CC or BCC counts as an individual email? So if I send 1 email with 1 CC, it will count as 2 emails. And the quote will be 2 of 100 . Sorry to post question here. Just in case you know.